# Referencing n rows in recursive cte

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to set logic such that the value of new columns is decisioned based on an external column in the same index and the prior n test columns.

```
with data (index, value1) as (
     select * from values
     (1,1),
     (2,1),
     (3,1),
     (4,1),
     (5,0),
     (6,0),
     (7,1),
     (8,1),
     (9,0),
     (10,1)
),
cte AS (
SELECT
  index
  ,value1
  ,test
FROM data
WHERE index = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  a.index
  ,a.value1
  ,case when a.value > 0 and b.test = 0 then 1 else 0 end as a.test
FROM data as a
INNER JOIN cte as b
ON b.index + 1 = a.index
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

I am trying to add a line that looks at if the last say 2 columns in test are 1 and if they are then to make the test column 0.

The above script yields the following:

| index | value1 | test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 1 | 1 |

I am trying to get it to program the script such that it tests for the value of "value1" and the value of the prior two test values such hat a value1 = 1 and the last 2 test values do not = 1. Below is an example of the output i would be looking for:

| index | value1 | test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 1 | 1 |

SQL wont let me nest a window function into a recursive cte.

Thanks

I have attempted to nest a lag function within the recursive cte but it isn't allowed.

Comment: Why would you need a recursive query? You can `select` directly from your `data` table, and apply the logic you want with window functions.

Comment: @MartinSmith I am using Snowflake

Comment: @GMB how do you mean? when i tried that it would propagate properly for long chains of value1 = 1

Comment: It is rather unclear to me what rule you want for `test`. Maybe it would help to explain the logic step by step, say for the first five rows in your dataset.

Comment: in the first part it tests "value1" to see if it is 1 or 0 then it tests if the previous value in the "test" column is 1 or 0. If value1 = 1 and test(t-1) =0 then test(t) = 1.

in the second part i wanted to look back an additional time period such that if value1 =1 and not (test(t-2) = 1 and test(t-1) = 1) would yield 1 @GMB

Comment: You can save prior value of test1 as test2, something like: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PNGQ-Wae).

Comment: Why is test = 0 for index = 1?  It seems that there are no 2 previous test values for that, so it should be 1.

Comment: a is an alias for data.  you refer to a.value, but there is no value column on data.  The code in your question can't work.

Comment: @PonderStibbons Thanks a bunch! this is what i was looking for although i still not 100%  understand how test2 is offset.  Additionally if i wanted to push this out to 3 or n tests back would i be able to?

Comment: @PonderStibbons nevermind i got it